# Calender settings in taskbar

Tags: gnome-calendar

How to change the year in the calendar of the top bar in Ubuntu 20.04 to check the weekday of a particular date from previous years?

Comment: it has to be done manually by clicking on ◄ to the left of the month in the calendar. There is no option to select a month or a year by default. An alternative would be to use Google Calendar in your browser which will allow you selections.

Comment: There is a GNOME alternative https://snapcraft.io/gnome-calendar. You can install it [here](https://snapcraft.io/install/gnome-calendar/ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in terminal:

```
cal 12 2020
```

in which 12 is the month number and 2020 the year and it displays that particular month.

Or

```
cal 2020
```

which displays the whole year.